# Python: Opening a set of dictionaries as a dataframe

Tags: python-2.7, performance, dictionary, set, data-cleaning

Most likely a rather basic question, but nevertheless

I have the following raw data file:

```
[{"column1":"value1","column2":"value2","column3":value3,},{"column1":"value4","column2":"value5","column3":value6},{"column1":"value7","column2":"value8","column3":value9}]
```

I need to have it as a dataframe in the following form:

```
   column1  column2  column3
    value1   value2   value3
    value4   value5   value6
    value7   value8   value9
```

As the file is rather large (1.2 million values over the 3 columns), what would be the fastest and most convenient way of opening it?

Any suggestions on what I should look into are highly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the pandas Documentation (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html):

d = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df

Answer (score 2):

You can use [from_dict](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html) function of pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
dat = [{"column1":"value1","column2":"value2","column3":"value3",},{"column1":"value4","column2":"value5","column3":"value6"},{"column1":"value7","column2":"value8","column3":"value9"}]

print(pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dat))
```

Result:

```
  column1 column2 column3
0  value1  value2  value3
1  value4  value5  value6
2  value7  value8  value9
```

Comment: That would be a solution, yet inserting 1.3 mm values and the respective column names is very very slow

Comment: It depends on what you call slow...I've done this on bigger dataset and pandas is quite efficient at reading file.